# wamp + oracle connection

Tags: php, oracle11g, wampserver

I have Windows server 2008 R 2 standard with wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b.

I have followed instructions provided by oracle, of course using wamp installation: [Article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html)

I used oracle instant client version: **instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.4.0**

Problem is, that when i enable these lines in **httpd.conf**, any php file called gives error **"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /path/file.php on this server."**:

```
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/new_wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/"
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FcgidWrapper "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php-cgi.exe" .php
```

Also there is error in php error log:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   **'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - %1** is not a valid
>   Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0

But **instantclient** is 32bit version. As far as i have found out from previous installations, mostly problem is in 64bit **instantclient**?

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: WAMPServer uses PHP as an Apache Extension and not FastCGI. Its possible to convert it to FastCGI but not necessary. I would imaging that you did not remove the Apache PHP module when you tried to use PHP as FastCGI either which may be your immediate issue.

Comment: Ok, so i need only to install **wamp** and **32bit instantclient** to be able to connect to oracle db?

Comment: This is only error i now receive. Module is uncommented and is in right path.  

    **Call to undefined function oci_connect()**

It is in php error log and on website. **phpinfo** tells correct path to **instantclient**. 

Bit out of ideas here..?

Comment: I got it to go bit forward. Now my php file gives following error:

**Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in C:\........**

Path is set in **enviroment settings** to **instantclient** folder. Where to check and what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Problem was, that it still used some 64bit files of instantclient. I had made a mistake while unzipping package.